# How to append a div to the body?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am supposed to assign .moon and .planet to the "planet" class and add a background colour to it, so I need to create a div. I have no idea on how to append a div to the body.

The code below shows what I'm currently trying. Please point out my mistake(s).

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Challenge: Create a solar system</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: black;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .planet {
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px;
                position: relative;
            }
            .moon {
                position: absolute;
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background: rgb(237, 237, 237);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <script>
    var bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");
    for (var i = 0; i < planetsNode.length; i++) {
        var planetsNode = document.createElement("div");
        planetsNode[i].className += "planet";
        planetsNode.body.backgroundColor = "rgb(235, 12, 235)";
        document.body.appendChild(planetsNode);
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try running your code.

Comment: What is `planetsNode`?

Comment: planetNode is not declared when you enter in your for.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the variable 'planetsNode' before it gets created and you are accessing body from 'planetNode' element while assigning background color.

Hope this might help.

```
<script>
 var body = document.querySelector("body");

 var planetsNode = document.createElement("div");       
 planetsNode.className = "planet";

 body.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(235, 12, 235)";
 body.appendChild(planetsNode);
</script>
```

I don't know why you are using loop.

Comment: The instructor then asks me "Are you using JS to set the background color of the div so that the planet actually shows up?" How do I do it then?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access 'length' property of the 'planetsNode' variable before it has been created.  If you are looking to create a new div for each planet create an array of planets and loop through them.

```
<script>
    var planets = [
        ["Mercury", "46.3, 46.3, 46.3"],
        ["Venus", "80.4, 78.4, 76.1"], 
        ["Earth", "34.9, 37.3, 51.4"], 
        ["Mars", "99.6, 52.9, 37.3"],
        ["Jupiter", "85.1, 74.9, 65.1"], 
        ["Saturn", "86.3, 73.7, 50.6"],
        ["Uranus", "76.5, 91.4, 92.5"],
        ["Neptune", "28.2, 47.5, 98.8"]
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < planets.length; i++) {

        var planetNode = document.createElement("div");
        planetNode.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(" + planets[i][1] + ")";

        var nameNode = document.createTextNode(planets[i][0]);
        planetNode.appendChild(nameNode);

        var body = document.querySelector("body");
        body.appendChild(planetNode);
    }
</script>
```